# How to add two object 2d array values in javaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, multidimensional-array, dom-events

This is the question

```
var x = [
   {amount:2,concentration:10},
   {amount:1,concentration:8},
   {amount:6,concentration:15}
];
```

expected output:

```
y = [{amount:9, concentration:33}];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) with an initial value equal to the first element of the array

```js
const x = [
    { amount: 2, concentration: 10 },
    { amount: 1, concentration: 8 },
    { amount: 6, concentration: 15 },
];

const result = x.reduce((acc, val) => ({
    amount: acc.amount + val.amount,
    concentration: acc.concentration + val.concentration,
}));

console.log(result);

const y = [result];

console.log(y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, here working example:

```js
var x =[
  {amount:2,concentration:10},
  {amount:1,concentration:8},
  {amount:6,concentration:15}
];

var result = {};
result.amount = x.map(item => item.amount).reduce((prev, next) => prev + next);
result.concentration = x.map(item => item.concentration).reduce((prev, next) => prev + next);
console.log([result]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use simple for loop

```js
const x =[
  {amount:2,concentration:10},
  {amount:1,concentration:8},
  {amount:6,concentration:15}
];

let y = [{
  amount: 0,
  concentration: 0
}];

for(let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  y[0].amount += x[i].amount;
  y[0].concentration += x[i].concentration;
}

console.log(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer but can be useful to many people.

```
var x =[
    {amount:2,concentration:10},
    {amount:1,concentration:8},
    {amount:6,concentration:15}
];

let totalAmount = 0;
let totalConcentration = 0;
x.map(xx => {
    totalAmount += xx.amount;
    totalConcentration += xx.concentration;
});
console.log({amount: totalAmount, concentration: totalConcentration});
```